# why javascript const keyword is not working in array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function home() {
  const list = ['john', 'adele', 'hary']; list.push('tiger');
  return list;
}
home() //["john", "adele", "hary", "tiger"]
```

push method is available and also, list[0] = "abc" is available

In JS, const keyword is different to Java or CPP??

Comment: No reassignment !== no mutation

Comment: With `list[0]` you are not mutating whole array, just assigning value to some index. Again with `Array.push` you are not mutating whole array, just you are adding something to the end of array.

Comment: You might be looking for [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Answer (score 1):

With a `const` declaration, you can't reassign the variable but you can mutate it, which is what happens with the `Array.prototype.push` method.

You won't be able to do like

```
function home() {
  const list = ['john', 'adele', 'hary']; 
  list = list.concat(['tiger']); // this is reassignment and hence will fail
  return list;
}
home()
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states:

1. constant cannot change through re-assignment
2. constant cannot be re-declared

You are not reassign value and not redeclare, therefore it's legal.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to push items into the array.
However, **assigning a new array** to the variable throws an error - Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

```
list = ['man','woman']; //ERROR IN YOUR CASE
```